# Setting SSLContext to org.apache.olingo.client.api.ODataClient

Tags: java, olingo

I have following error failed to `loadODataResources`.

```
org.apache.olingo.client.api.http.HttpClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Comment: Please add sample code and/or stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The error seemed to have to do with SSL connection handshakes. In general, I would look to env variables to customize SSLContext. In your case, "https.protocols" may be helpful, such as:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

Please see following references for more details:

1. [Remote host closed connection during handshake when using in multithreaded environement #748](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/748)
2. [Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)
3. [JDK 9's JSSE doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-9A577D22-9DED-407E-9F16-5C006E3F3BF3)